# Loading Data in sameTableViewController based on button press Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on a sample iOS app and want to load (in a tableViewController) certain data based on the button the user presses at the top of the view. For example, when the user loads the page it will by default load data from "myPosts" but on the top of the view there will be two buttons "My Posts", "Not My Posts". If they then select the "Not My Posts" button then the tableview cells will be reloaded with the data from "notMyPosts". Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: What issue are you having? Do you know how to load a table view with one set of data? Do you know how to handle a button press? Do you know how to get both sets of data?

Comment: I know how to load a table view with one set of data, I know how to handle a button press, I do not know how to get both sets of data.

Comment: Then you need to focus on that first. Get to the point where you can load one set of data or the other. Then you can work on get one or the other based on the selected button.

Comment: are you trying to achieve something like a [segmentedControl](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aTjYU.png)?

Comment: I think a segmented Contro is the best aproach in this case :)

Comment: segmentControll looks like exactly what I want! I have never used it. Could you briefly explain what it does?

Comment: just start writing an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the best solution here is to use a Segmented Control. Basically, you will have a controller for each TableView and a controller for the SegmentedControl.

This [tutorial](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/segmented-control-tutorial-ios8-swift) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956353/swift-segmented-control-switch-multiple-views) gives a basic idea on the segmentedControl and how to set the basic controller for it. You will basically have a Container View with a view for each tableView you want to display and show/hide it based on the selected segment on the SegmentedControl.

This is how your storyboard will look like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Very Helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Just use two different datasources for your table, depending on which button the user selects.

So, when the user taps on a button set a variable to keep track of which button they tapped, and then reload your tableview.

Comment: So then I would use an if statement to handle which data is loaded?

Comment: Yes, that's one way of solving it.

Comment: Or use one variable to store the current datasource for your table. You then update this variable to point to different datasources when the buttons are tapped and then you reload the table. This works best if the datasources all have the same structure/properties, of course.

Comment: Ok so would that work better than my proposed if statement? They would have the exact same structure

Comment: Yes, in that case you only need one if statement - when deciding what the datasource variable should point to.