# How to implement Tab bar in swift?

Tags: swift

I tried working on tab bars on top of the view controller ,we can do default tab bars by using xcode storyboard .but i need to build custom tab bars on top of my screen in ios app by using swift 2.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - Segmented control - Switch multiple views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956353/swift-segmented-control-switch-multiple-views)

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot change the UITabBar position**

See this :

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbar